# React native, getting very slow after handleStateChange

Tags: react-native

Once the following code is run, my app is getting very very slow..

I open a screen which has the following code and immediatly closes it via backbutton, from then on, app is getting very slow.

What could be the reason?

```
 const [appState, setAppState] = useState(null)

   useEffect(() => {
     AppState.addEventListener('change', _handleAppStateChange)

     return () => {
       AppState.removeEventListener('change', _handleAppStateChange)
     }
   }, [])

   const _handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
     console.log('state', appState, nextAppState)
     if (
       nextAppState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
       (appState == null || appState === 'active')
     ) {
       console.log('App is going to background!')
       editDispatch({
         type: 'saveTemp',
         payload: state,
       })
     }
     setAppState(nextAppState)
   }
```